# Substract one day of date in Jasper

Tags: java, date, jasper-reports, days, date-manipulation

i have this code in my JasperReport like that `new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(new Date()) - 24 * 3600 * 1000` but it's not working, what i'm trying is substract one day from today. But it's displaying the day of today like that

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Test: " + new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(new Date()) - 24 * 3600 * 1000]]></textFieldExpression>
```

Comment: You might be try new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - (24 * 3600 * 1000))

Comment: Yeah it's working with new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - (24 * 3600 * 1000))) . Thank you a lot

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It also makes subtracting a day easier and easier to get correct (subtracting 24 * 3600 * 1000 milliseconds is not always correct).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, this code obviously ignores the `- 24 * 3600 * 1000` because the expression `new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(new Date())` determines the value **before** you try to subtract one day ignoring the arithmetic that follows. It only considers the `new Date()`, which is today.

You should include the calculation before formatting, e.g.

```java
new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - (24 * 3600 * 1000)))
```

If you are on Java 8 or higher, I would use `java.time`, maybe like this:

```java
LocalDate.now().minusDays(1).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu")
```